# Limitar un campo del editor visual de WordPress en el envio de un post

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Estoy usando un plugin llamado `USP PRO` para enviar contenidos desde un formulario, sin embargo se me presenta el siguiente problema:

Tengo un [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para limitar el número de palabras:

```
$('.usp-input-content').keyup(function(){
        var limit = 500; // word limit
        var count = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
        $('.counter').html(count);
        if (count > limit) {
            alert('Recuerda : Tu texto debe tener máximo 500 palabras!');
            return false;
        }
});
```

Este código funciona en la pestaña `Texto`, pero al activar el editor visual de [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) como es un `iframe` no me deja validar la cantidad de palabras enviadas en el formulario.

¿Alguien podría darme una mano para poder validar este dato?

Answer (score 2):

Con TinyMCE puedes añadir controladores de eventos cuando inicias el editor mediante el parámetro `setup`. Así en tu inicialización de TinyMCE, deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'.usp-input-content',
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on("keyup", function() {

            // el código que quieres para el evento keyup

        });
    }
});
```

Podrías copiar y pegar tú código para el evento `keyup` y ponerlo dentro de la función que lo controla para el editor. Lo único que tendrías que cambiar es `$(this).val()` que ya no funcionaría, y en su lugar usar `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` que devolverá el contenido del editor TinyMCE activo.

Así el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'.usp-input-content',
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on("keyup", function() {
            var limit = 500; // word limit
            var count = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
            $('.counter').html(count);
            if (count > limit) {
                alert('Recuerda : Tu texto debe tener máximo 500 palabras!');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

**Si no tienes control sobre cuándo se inicializan los editors de TinyMCE** y por lo tanto no puedes añadir `setup` con los controladores de eventos, puedes esperar a que se cargue la página y, una vez inicializados los editores TinyMCE, añadir los eventos.

La parte de "*una vez inicializados los editores TinyMCE*" es esencial en este caso. Así que para asegurarnos que se han inicializado, ejecutaremos el siguiente código al final de la página usando `setTimeout` para dar tiempo a TinyMCE a iniciar los editores:

```
// 100ms después de que se cargue la página (puede que necesites ajustar este valor)
setTimeout(function() {

    // comprueba todos los editores de TinyMCE
    for (var x = 0; x < tinymce.editors.length; x++) {

        // si tienen la clase que quieres
        if (tinymce.editors[x].targetElm.className == "usp-input-content") {

            // añade el evento onkeyup con tu código
            tinymce.editors[x].on("keyup", function(editor, e) {
                var limit = 500; // word limit
                var count = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
                $('.counter').html(count);
                if (count > limit) {
                    alert('Recuerda : Tu texto debe tener máximo 500 palabras!');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, 100);
```